# Angular 4, convert http response observable to object observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm new to the concepts of observables and need some help with a conversion.
I have a service which returns an `Observable<Response>` from a Http request, but I need to convert it do an `Observable<PriceTag>` to use it on a `DataSource` inside the connect method.
Is there anyway to do this?

This is the method from my service:

```
getPriceTags(): Observable<Response> {

    // Set the request headers
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    // Returns the request observable
    return this.http.post(Constants.WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS + "/priceTag", null, {headers: headers});

}
```

And here is the DataSource class where I need to return it as an `Observable<PriceTag>`:

```
export class PriceTagDataSource extends DataSource<PriceTag> {

    constructor (private priceTagService: PriceTagService) {
        super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<PriceTag> {

        // Here I retrieve the Observable<Response> from my service
        const respObs = this.priceTagService.getPriceTags();

        // Now I need to return a Observable<PriceTag> 

    }

    disconnect() {}

}
```

Here's an example from the response from my request:

```
{
    // This object is used to check if the query on the server was sucessful
    "query": {
        "sucessful": true
    },

    // These are my PriceTags 
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "MAIN"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "CARD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did one of the answers help you?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As of angular 4.3 this can be done automatically.

Example:

```
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}  // <--- NOTE: HttpClient instead of Http

    getSome(): Observable<MyAwesomeObject> {
        return this.http.get<MyAwesomeObject>('myUrl');
    }
}
```

So in your case that would be:

`return this.http.post<PriceTag>(Constants.WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS + "/priceTag", null, {headers: headers});`

Again, use the `HttpClient` instead of `Http`

Comment: Ooooh i didn't know it could do that... neat

Comment: is there a difference between that and
`getSome(): Observable<MyAwesomeObject> {

        return this.http.get('myUrl').map((response) => 

<MyAwesomeObject>response.json());
    }`

Comment: For me this doesn't actually create the PriceTag object. The data is still of type Object.

Comment: Hi, 
I have a small question. There is something I do not understand, in this solution I indeed can get all properties of instance of MyAwsomeObject but in case thic class would also have some public method I am not able to access it - so it looks like json representation of MyAwsomeObject - not instance of it itself.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok.. I found an answer to my comment.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102824/no-methods-in-http-response-object

Comment: But what if a need to convert the HTTP response to a different type? Something like AutoMapper in the .net world?

Answer (score 5):

I guess your HTTP Response is a JSON containing a PriceTag? 
The issue is that you want to create a PriceTag object. You can just convert the json to a PriceTag by type casting, but then it won't be a real PriceTag object.

The way we have resolved this is:

```
export class Serializable {
  constructor(json?: any) {
    if (json) {
      Object.assign(this, json);
    }
  }
}
```

And then a serializable class:

```
export class PriceTag extends Serializable {}
```

Then, your GetPriceTags function needs to be changed to:

```
getPriceTags(): Observable<PriceTag> {

    // Set the request headers
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    // Returns the request observable
    return this.http.post(Constants.WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS + "/priceTag", null, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => new PriceTag(res.json()));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Angular 4+`, It can be done automatically.
You can change your `getPriceTags` method:

```
export class PriceTagService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getPriceTags<T>(): Observable<T> {

        // Set the request headers
        const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

        // Returns the request observable
        return this.http.post<T>(`${Constants.WEBSERVICE_ADDRESS}/priceTag`, null, {headers: headers});

    }
}
```

And your `DataSource` class can be:

```
export class PriceTagDataSource extends DataSource<PriceTag> {
    constructor (private priceTagService: PriceTagService) {
        super();
    }

    connect(): Observable<PriceTag> {
        // Here you can retrieve the Observable<PriceTag> from service and return directly
        return this.priceTagService.getPriceTags<PriceTag>();
    }

    disconnect() {}
}
```